# jQuery Get Function change to make asynchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some old code which I've now being asked to make asynchronous.

It's basically a jQuery GET function ... like this:

```
jQuery.get("my url", function(data){

    //code here

});
```

How can I make this asynchronous?

Comment: because the "// code here" block only executes after the data is retrieved from the URL, your code already *is* asynchronous

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing the words **synchronous** and **asynchronous**?

Comment: you need to passin a callback to be called when the ajax call succeeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default jQuery.get is an asynchronous call , to make it synchronous you have to set it

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

Comment: Why would he want to make it synchronous?

Comment: Oh, so it's already asynchronous ? I though it was synchronous by default ... it my function is already asynchronous...then that's done already :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mistyped your question—ajax calls are asynchronous by default, but here is how you would make it synchronous.

The best way would be to use the long-form ajax request (for which jQuery.get() is shorthand).

It would look like the following

```
jQuery.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "my url",
  async: false,
  data: data,
  success: function(data){},
});
```

The reason why `jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});` is bad form is because it makes every ajax call synchronous, not just the individual call you want to change.